# Cordova 3.5.0 FileTransfer + NodeJS (multipart/form-data) upload issue

Tags: node.js, file, cordova, multipartform-data, transfer

Cordova 3.5.0, file-transfer plugin Android js file.

```
  var ft = new FileTransfer();
  var options = new FileUploadOptions();
  options.fileKey="files";
  options.fileName=path.substr(path.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
  options.mimeType="video/mp4";
  options.headers = {Connection: "close"};
  options.chunkedMode = false;
  options.httpMethod = 'POST';

  ft.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
    if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
      loadingStatus.setPercentage(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total);
    } else {
      loadingStatus.increment();
    }
    colsole.log(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total);
  };

  ft.upload(path, uri, win, fail, options);
```

Node.JS server

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
    console.log('upload req:'+util.inspect(req.files));
}
```

Console.log returns "undefined" for req.files. Works fine with Native Android program and web upload.

Comment: What does `console.dir(req.headers['content-type']);` show?

Comment: rawHeaders:
   [ 'X-Real-IP',
     '192.168.0.161',
     'X-Forwarded-For',
     '192.168.0.161',
     'X-Forwarded-Proto',
     'http',
     'Host',
     '192.168.0.110',
     'X-NginX-Proxy',
     'true',
     'Content-Length',
     '0',
     'Content-Type',
     'multipart/form-data; boundary=+++++',
     'files',
     'file:/data/data/com.somevid/cache/Capture.avi',
     'Data',
     'Test',
     'Data',
     'param',
     'User-Agent',
     'Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; SGH-I897 Build/KVT49L)',
     'Accept-Encoding',
     'gzip' ],
  trailers: {},
  rawTrailers: [],

Comment: `Content-Length` is 0? Perhaps that could be why you're not getting anything on the server...

Comment: Ya, i'm not completely sure. I have opted to use the native android. It's light weight and works.

Comment: Thanks for checking into this. When I try again with Cordova, I'll see why the content-length is infact 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ExpressJs (which it looks like you're using), then you need to install Multer middleware to handle multipart data.

https://github.com/expressjs/multer